# Approach to store user login and password on database when there are some roles totally different

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating site and there are 3 roles on it. Administrator, Teacher, Parent. User with any role has access to site, but 1 role has full access, teachers can only put marks for students, parents can only watch these marks.
I understand how to separate roles into scripts. Just save some parameter depending on what database would return when I check login and password.

So! Administrator has only `login name and username`. Also it is possible to store information about how to contact the user to make system more user-friendly. That's all.

Teacher has `firstname, lastname, midname (father's name), address, phone` etc. And it must have login and password fields...

Parent has `Firstname, Lastname, Midname` only. And sure somewhere I should to store data about login and password.

So should I just check this tables 1 by 1 and depending on table I will find $login and $password I inputted in I will return role?  I don't think it is a nice idea. Suggest something else please.

What I think to do. I think that it would be not very bad idea if I will create 1 more table like `users` where I will store: `id, username, login, role, user_id` (need to think about it). The problem is user_id. How exactly this table will be connected to others? For example user_id` would be 1. 101% there would be 1 row with such id.

I want to ask about exprience of your self-build systems. May you suggest something please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It doesn't make sense to have different tables for users. I would recommend you to store authorization and personal data in separate tables. And of course you'll need additional table for roles:

[image: simple users storage]

The idea behind this scheme is to keep thin `users` table for fast authorization. If authorization was successful, than you should check permissions from `roles` or get personal data from `user_data` tables.

Look at this [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71973) for DDL.

Comment: Thank you! So administrator, parent and teacher will store in one table, right?

Comment: Yes, i think you don't need separate them. Just keep empty not used fields like `firstname`, `lastname` and `midname` for Administrators.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to start what you suggest, but realised I have half system linked with my old database model, where admin, parents and pupils where separated tables :( Your idea is very nice of course, but I have only 5 hours before exam! :(

Comment: Btw, I think `users <=> user_data` should be another type. `users 0..1 <=> 1 user_data`. `Teachers` and `Parents` were linked to many others table. I just should link all that tables to `user_data` now, right? In my system it would be possible to create 1 new row connected with `roles` so it would be **1 teacher**, **1 parent** or **1 administrator**. If row in `users` linked with this `user_data.id` table is created, this person would be available to log in. Right? I think it would be better to name this tables another way then. Am I correct? Do  you understand me?

Comment: Also it is possible to make `user <=> user_data` link next: `users 1 <=> 1 user_data` and possibly merge this two tables. It would work if any teacher, admin or parent MUST HAVE login and password, like in my system, right?

Comment: Ah 5 minutes! Can't edit old comment! Is there a reason to separate this tables? Only beause 1-many link? But 1 `user` row can't be linked with many `user_data` rows, right?

Comment: So many questions, I'll try to answer :) If you have other tables linked with`Teachers` and `Parents`, yes, it's better to redefine references to `user_data`. Users with roles associated as zero or many to zero or 1 `users` 0..* <=> 0..1 `roles`. Users with data associated as one to zero or one `users` 1 <=> 0..1 `user_data`. In my scheme any user must have login and pass (they're not null). For user authorization you doesn't need user data, that's why `users` and `user_data` separated. It's different functional entities.